# Function returns nothing rather than the expected value "None"

Tags: python, function, return

I have no return put into my function, so I thought it should return "None".  Instead, it simply does not return anything.  Can someone tell me why?  All help appreciated!

```
def posdivisor(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            print(i)

someValue = eval(input("Enter an integer: "))

posdivisor(someValue)
```

**THE SHELL REPORTS:**

```
Enter an integer: 49
1
7
49
```

Comment: what you see the the print executed in the console.

Comment: Are you doing this in the interactive shell?  If `None` is returned, the shell doesn't display anything.  If you do `posdivisor(someValue)` you should see "None" printed.

Comment: Using `eval` this way is _evil_. Use `int` instead!

Comment: I am doing the code in a file, and then printing to the shell.  I think the shell does print "None" if it is supposed to, because if I change the last line in the code to "print(posdivisor(someValue))" then the shell prints "None".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your code just print data, the function return a `None`, and you ignore it, try to print out will see None:

```
def posdivisor(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            print(i)

someValue = eval(input("Enter an integer: "))

result = posdivisor(someValue)
print result
```

Besides, you don't need `eval()` here, just `input()` will be ok if you can insure that input is always number:

```
def posdivisor(n):
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            print(i)

someValue = input("Enter an integer: ")

result = posdivisor(someValue)
print result
```

Answer (score 0):

the python prompt will automatically swallow `None`'s when evaluating things interactively:

```
>>> def foo(): return None
>>> foo()
>>> None
>>> repr(None)
'None'
```